# knex with PostgreSQL use string_agg for select getting Expected 1 bindings, saw 0 error

Tags: postgresql, binding, knex.js

knex with PostgreSQL use string_agg for select getting error:

> Expected 1 binding, saw 0

```
let qry = knex( this.buisness_types )
          .select([ 'buisness_types._id', 'buisness_types.title', 
                  knex.raw('string_agg(DISTINCT categories.title,',') as email')] ) 
          .innerJoin('categories', 'buisness_types._id', 'categories.buisnessTypeId')
          .where( "buisness_types.status",1 )
          .where( "categories.status",1 )
          .groupBy('buisness_types._id')
          .toString();
console.log('query data',qry);
```

Comment: Your query doesn't mention `string_agg` -- can you clarify your question?

Comment: i want to use string_agg ,when i am use string_agg   using knex getting error. without string_agg query run sucessfully

Comment: Try replacing your single quotes with double quotes: `knex.raw('string_agg(DISTINCT categories.title,',')` -> `knex.raw('string_agg(DISTINCT categories.title,",")`

Comment: knex.raw('string_agg(DISTINCT categories.title,',') -> knex.raw('string_agg(DISTINCT categories.title,",") –  get generate error    ERROR: column "," does not exist
LINE 1: ...es"."title", string_agg(DISTINCT categories.title,",")

Comment: i got a issue the right query is  knex( this.buisness_types )
        .select( 
            "buisness_types._id",
            "buisness_types.title",
            knex.raw( "STRING_AGG( DISTINCT categories.title,',') as category" ) )
        .innerJoin('categories', 'buisness_types._id', 'categories.buisnessTypeId')
        .where( "buisness_types.status",1 )
        .where( "categories.status",1 )
        .groupBy("buisness_types._id")